# Reduce/reduce conflict in a C-style cast operator

Tags: bison, reduce-reduce-conflict

I am writing a bison+flex parser for a certain query language and I need to add a C-style cast operator to it. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
%token <characterToken>  Identifier
%token <commandToken>    LRPAR RRPAR

%type <characterToken>   typename
%type <operationValue>   generalExp castExp variable

%%
generalExp: variable
      | LRPAR generalExp RRPAR
       { /* some code here */ }
      | castExp
      ;

castExp: LRPAR typename RRPAR generalExp
   { /* some code here */ }
   ;

variable: Identifier 
    { /* some code here*/ };
typename: Identifier;
%%
```

The problem here is that `(typename)` in `castExp` clashes with `(variable)` in `generalExp` and gives a reduce/reduce conflict:

```
test.yy: conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce
test.yy:23.11-20: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: typename: Identifier
```

Possible solution could be to list all valid typenames (like long, int, char) in the corresponding  lex file, however I need to support used-defined types as well.

UPD: 
another solution is to use bison GLR-parser, which I don't want due to performance drop.

`bison -v` output is [here](http://pastebin.com/VU0jtqem).

Comment: What is the `bison -v` output for the states with the conflict?

Comment: The conflict message is related to the warning about `typename`: when the parser sees a `)` after an `Identifier`, it doesn't know whether to reduce it to `variable` or `typename`. That's the reduce/reduce conflict. It chooses to solve the conflict by always reducing to `variable` because that production is earlier in the grammar. That makes `typename` useless, so then it generates the warning. However, none of that answers your question, I don't think. I attempted to answer your question separately; if you like, I can add this comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `C` cast syntax was very badly chosen. It is impossible to resolve correctly without knowing whether what is inside the cast is a type or a value. Here are some cases in C:

```
(f)*a    // cast the value pointed to by a to type f, or multiply f by a?
(f)(a+b) // cast a+b to type f or call the function f with argument a+b?
```

The easiest way I've found to handle this is to let the lexer consult the symbol table, so that it can return different token types for Typenames and Identifiers. (Which is pretty well the way the C grammar works.) Sharing the symbol table between the lexer and the parser is a bit ugly, particularly if you allow scoped type definitions, but it can be done. For the purposes of correct lexing, the only thing that the lexer should need to know is whether the symbol is the name of a type or not; you can probably get away with assuming that a symbol is not a type unless it has been explicitly declared a type, so that it is not strictly necessary to insist that all symbols be declared before use. (In C++, for example, a non-type class member does not have to be declared before use, and that can still work.)

Having said all that, I'd strongly encourage you to think seriously about using a different syntax for casts, if at all possible. Aside from being a pain for parsers, they can also be annoyingly ambiguous for human readers (see the examples above), and casting is not (or should not be) so common that it requires an abbreviated syntax.

C++-style casts -- `cast<TYPE>(value)` -- suffer from the ambiguity introduced by recycling a comparison operator as a bracket, but are tolerable if the operations using angle brackets are a fixed set of keywords. (Otherwise, you create another context where the lexer needs to distinguish between name kinds.)

Personally, particularly for a query language, I'd go with something like

```
value as type
```

as in

```
(3 + 4) as double
```

which is (IMO) more readable and much easier to parse without being harder to type.

Comment: Yes, one of the possible solutions is to introduce different tokens for Typenames with limited set of keyworks, but I need to support user-defined types, which were defined outside of the scope of the query.

Introducing another syntax for the cast operator probably would be the best solution.

Comment: @apchhee: That's why I suggested giving the lexer access to a syntax table. If I have time, I'll modify the answer to provide an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Giving the lexer access to the syntax table works, many thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess -- some other part of your grammar that you don't show allows for two consecutive `generalExp` with no token between them.  So when you have an input like `( Identifier ) expression`, it might be either a cast or two consecutive `generalExp`s.

The way to proceed is the same as with all conflicts -- run bison with the `-v` option to get a `.output` file showing all the states and exactly which states have what conflicts on which symbols.  Once you know that, you have a chance of figuring out what can be done.

Comment: No, none of the rules allows two consecutive generalExp's, so the parser fails trying to process such expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - colision of following rules:

```
expr: expr "+" expr
expr: "(" type ")" expr
```

I solved it by setting precedence of operators:

```
%precedence "+"
%precedence ")"
```

This set higher precedence to `")"`, so the second rule will be prefered.